# sql loader not loading all the needed rows due to new line character and enclosement character

Tags: sql-loader

I have a problem with how SQL loader manage the end of a column value. I was hoping to manage CR LF, the enclosement character and the separator character but it seems I can't find a solution!

The data I receive from the .csv file looks like this:

```
"C","I","FLAGS","LASTUPDATEDATE","BOEVERSION","C_OSUSER_UPDATEDBY","I_OSUSER_UPDATEDBY","C_OSUSER_PWF","DESCRIPTION","DURATION","ENDDATE","I_OSUSER_PWF","LASTSTATUSCHA","STARTDATE","DURATIONUNIT","TYPE","STATUS","C_BNFTRGHT_CONDITIONS","I_BNFTRGHT_CONDITIONS","C_CNTRCT1_CONDITION","I_CNTRCT1_CONDITION","EXTBLOCKTYPE","EXTBLOCKDURATIONUNIT","EXTBLOCKDURATION","EXTBLOCKDESCRIPTION","PARTITIONID"
"7680","423","PE","2015-07-06 11:42:10","0","1000","1506","","No benefits are payable for a Total Disability period during a Parental or Family-Related Leave, for a Total Disability occurring during this period.
","0","","","","","69280000","69312015","71328000","7285","402","","","","","","","1"
"7680","426","PE","2015-07-06 11:42:10","0","1000","1506","","""Means to be admitted to a Hospital as an in-patient for more than 18 consecutive hours.



""
","0","","","","","69280000","69312021","71328000","7285","402","","","","","","","1"
```

My ctl file is as follow:

```
Load Data
infile 'C:\2020-07-29-03-04-48-TolCondition.csv'
CONTINUEIF LAST != '"'
into table TolCondition
REPLACE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED by '"'
(
C,
I,
FLAGS,
LASTUPDATEDATE DATE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS",
BOEVERSION,
C_OSUSER_UPDATEDBY,
I_OSUSER_UPDATEDBY,
C_OSUSER_PWF,
DESCRIPTION CHAR(1000),
DURATION,
ENDDATE DATE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS",
I_OSUSER_PWF,
LASTSTATUSCHA DATE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS",
STARTDATE DATE "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS",
DURATIONUNIT,
TYPE,
STATUS,
C_BNFTRGHT_CONDITIONS,
I_BNFTRGHT_CONDITIONS,
C_CNTRCT1_CONDITION,
I_CNTRCT1_CONDITION,
EXTBLOCKTYPE,
EXTBLOCKDURATIONUNIT,
EXTBLOCKDURATION,
EXTBLOCKDESCRIPTION,
PARTITIONID)
```

Here is what I tried in the control file:

```
CONTINUEIF LAST != '"'
CONTINUEIF THIS PRESERVE (1:2) != '",'
"str X'220D0A'"
```

Here is the result I currently have with "CONTINUEIF LAST != '"'

```
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table TOLCONDITION, column DESCRIPTION.
second enclosure string not present
Record 3: Rejected - Error on table TOLCONDITION, column C.
no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field

Table TOLCONDITION:
  1 Row successfully loaded.
  2 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
```

Is there any way to manage line break and enclosement character in SQL Loader? I dont understand why we can`t change how it sees rows. Instead of seeing a new row when there is a CR LF, can we tell it to concacenate values until the last enclosement character (chr34 in my case) +  the separator character (, in my case) has been seen.

I really hope to find a way to resolve this issue without having to change the .csv file.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on 12c you can use the "FIELDS CSV WITH EMBEDDED" clause to tell `sqlldr` that some columns have the data file's end of line character embedded within.  This will cause the column to be inserted as it is in the data file.  More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-D1762699-8154-40F6-90DE-EFB8EB6A9AB0)

```
Load Data
infile 'C:\2020-07-29-03-04-48-TolCondition.csv'
into table TolCondition
REPLACE
FIELDS CSV WITH EMBEDDED TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```